# Git clobbering new changes with stale changes without raising conflicts

Tags: git, merge, version-control

So we're having an issue with our git repository that I can't imagine is very common (or else why would anyone use git?)

We have our main branch (Branch A), where a file has been changed.  As part of our release process, we create a release branch (Branch B). Nobody touched the file in Branch B, while changes were made in Branch A.  With the release done (bugs and what not), we merge Branch B back into Branch A, and discover that all of the old changes made in Branch A have been lost, and the Branch B version is taken (reverting the file to what was done before the merge)

Graphically (to the right is later time)

```
A--ch1---*---ch2---ch3--ch4----m---

          \                   /

           B------------------
```

So now that we are merging at `m`, git is silently choosing to keep the ch1 changes.

**UPDATE**

Additionally, we tried merging A into B at point m, and yet it's the same behaviour (git tries to make ch1 the latest change).

**UPDATE 2**
Based on torek's answer below, I followed the steps and discovered that the merge base is somewhere between ch3 and ch4 on the graph above.

Which to me raises more questions than it answers, because why is it not just applying the ch4 changes, based on what happened after the merge base.

And why does it think that ch1 (which in our case is the initial commit), should be applied over all subsequent changes.

Are we using git wrong? Is there something we're missing? This makes no sense to me from a user's point of view.

How do we make sure that this doesn't happen and that work isn't lost?  Thank you for any help.

Comment: You're right, I wanted to draw it going down first, but changed my mind. Right is later time, as per usual.

Comment: My only thought is that the branch was created incorrectly or the merge is being performed incorrectly.  This is abnormal behavior, if I'm understanding your explanation.

Comment: @zzxyz The new branch was created using Visual studio,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/branches?tabs=visual-studio shows the process (I don't actually use the VS git tools myself, but this is how it was created).
The merge was done similarly, but I have since then tried doing it through sourcetree and bitbucket (I assume that they just execute the merge command).  Is there something that we should watch out for?

Comment: merging a branch with no changes (B) from its point of creation back into its parent branch should be a no-op.  "Already up-to-date."  should be git's output.  There's actually no reason to do it.  Nothing to watch out for comes to mind...although I'm sure there's plenty.

Comment: if you do `git checkout B` and then `git log` (SourceTree has a terminal in its menus somewhere), it'll show commits to that branch in reverse order...the latest (first entry) should be ch1.  And then if you do `git checkout A` and `git log` you should see "ch4, ch3, ch2 ch1".  If that's NOT what you see, that's a place to start

Comment: Sorry, you don't even need to do that:  `git log B` and then `git log A` will do the trick

Comment: @zzxyz I ran `git log B` and `git log A`, and I saw what I expected: the commits `ch2,ch3,ch4` in reverse chronological order on A, and no mention of these commits on B. I'm not sure what else I can look at.  I will try to go through and see if the logs make mention of the file being updated by other commits, but I don't think that's likely - the file is identical to the version `ch1`.

Comment: @Kolichikov Is your problem solved now?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT It is not. At this point the above issue has happened a few more times, with always the same nonsensical commit returned as the merge-base (nonsensical because it can't be the mergebase, since it's a commit on a branch nobody branched from). My current theory is that git treated it as a merge instead of a commit and actually DID merge it into the branch, but I don't know how to undo that (or remove it from the git graph, since it's been a few weeks now and there are many subsequent changes).

Comment: @Kolichikov The merged version commit `m` should based on it's parents commit `B` and `ch4` as the graph you showed. As you said the merged version same as `ch1`, that's weird. Can you share the related commits in a example repo so that we can better detect the problem. Besides, if you want to remove the commits while new changes are committed after that, you can create a temp branch to backup the current version, then use `git reset --hard commit` to an old commit, and finally rebase the new changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot tell you why you got the result that you got.

I can, however, tell you how *you* can *find out* why.

#### Step 1: forget about branches, just look at *commits*

When you run `git merge`, Git does not really "merge branches": that's a higher level fiction we tell ourselves to make it easier to think about.  Instead, Git's `git merge` has two major parts.  The first is *merge as a verb*, which consists of finding some sets of changes and combining them.  The second is *merge as a noun (or adjective)*, which consists of making a commit that in most ways, is just like any other commit.  What's special about this merge commit—there it is: merge as an adjective, in front of the word "commit"—is that it has two *parent* commits, instead of the usual single parent.  This "having two parents" affects the way that *future* merge-as-a-verb operations will work.

#### Merge as a verb

In order to perform the merging action, Git needs to run two `git diff` commands.<sup>1</sup>  These two `git diff` commands compare some specific commit, what Git calls the *merge base* commit, against two other specific commits, which Git usually calls *branch tips*.

The branch tips are just what you would expect, given a drawing of a graph where later commits are towards the right, and branch *names* act as pointers to the tip-most commits:

```
       A1--A2--A3   <-- branch-A
      /
...--*
      \
       B1--B2--B3   <-- branch-B
```

The *merge base*, which I marked with `*` here, is, loosely speaking, the right-most commit at which the two branches rejoin.  When the branches forked off very simply like these do, it's obvious which commit is the merge base.  Once you've made several earlier merges, it's less obvious.

In any case, Git makes you choose one commit by running `git checkout` or `git commit`.  Whatever commit you have checked out right now, such as the tip of `branch-A`, is the *current* commit.<sup>2</sup>  There are several more names for the current commit, including `HEAD` and `@`, but in general there's always some current commit.  Checking out a branch by name makes the tip of that branch be the current commit.  Let's call this commit *L*, for Left or Local or `--ours`, so that we have a handy one-letter name for it.

Git will make *you* choose the other commit.  You can run `git merge <hash-id>` or `git merge <name>`.  No matter which you use, Git will find a hash ID for the commit and hence be able to work directly with this other commit.  Let's call it *R*, for Right or Remote or `--theirs`.

But now, Git will choose the merge base on its own.  It will do that by looking at the commit graph: commits *L* and *R*, the parent commit(s) of *L* and *R*, the parents' parents, and so on, until it finds where the commit chains meet up.

#### Step 2: finding the merge base

This is where you need command-line Git.  GUI tools are useless here.  In order to see what Git is doing, you must find the merge base commit yourself.  You can do this with the command line interface:

```
$ git merge-base --all L R    # you can use names or hash IDs here
```

Git will print out all the merge bases it finds, by their hash IDs.  Ideally, there will be exactly one merge base.  If there is more than one merge base, you have a complicated case (these result from "criss cross merges") and we have to dive deeper; but almost always, there's just one hash ID.

Save this hash ID (copy with mouse, save it in a shell variable, write it down, whatever).  You will need it twice.

#### Step 3: finding the changes since the base

Now, look at what Git will see as "what we changed":

```
$ git diff --find-renames <merge-base> L
```

This compares the merge base to the *L* commit.  Whatever differences turn up here, this is what Git thinks *we* did.  You might want to save this diff output to a file, so that you can peruse it more easily.

Then, do the same thing but for the *R* commit:

```
$ git diff --find-renames <merge-base> R
```

This is what Git thinks *they* did, in their branch.  Again, you may want to save this diff output to a file.

Git will now *combine* these two sets of changes.  Whatever we changed, Git applies those changes to the base.  Whatever *they* changed, Git applies those changes to the base, too.

If those changes are what you expected, and you combine them, you should get the combination you expected too.  Probably, those changes *aren't* what you expected, and you've found the source of your problem.

In any case, after Git has—or thinks it has—combined all the changes successfully, Git will commit this combined result.  The new commit will go on your current branch just like any other commit, but will have two parents.  The first parent will be commit *L* and the second parent will be commit *R*.

Note that the result of combining changes is symmetric: it doesn't matter which commit is *L* and which is *R*.  Whether you `git checkout branch-A` and then `git merge branch-B`, or `git checkout branch-B` and then `git merge branch-A`, the *source tree* you get will be the same.  What's different is which branch gets the merge commit, and which of *L* and *R* is the first or second parent.

You can also now run `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` and search the output for the merge base commit hash (or the abbreviated part of it) that you found when you ran `git merge-base`.  You can look at the graph that `--graph` drew and try to figure out *why* that's the correct merge base of the two commits you chose as *L* and *R*.  It *is* the correct merge base, even if you don't think so, and you don't get a choice about it: you only get to choose *L* and *R*.  These graphs often get very tangled, so that it's hard to figure out *why* it's the right merge base; but it always is.

---

<sup>1</sup>Internally, Git manages to skip a lot of the actual `git diff`-ing, in a lot of cases, to make it all go (much) faster; but that's all optimization on top of a logical process by which we can reason about what Git will do.

<sup>2</sup>This is true at all times: Git always has some current commit.  Well, *almost* all times: in a new, empty repository, there are no commits at all, so there is no current commit either.  There is also a special case after `git checkout --orphan <newbranch>`: you are, in this case, on an "unborn branch", and there is as yet no current commit.  The way Git handles this varies a bit from one command to another.  Let's just pretend it doesn't happen, here. :-)

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. I found the merge base, so I got the log, which gave me a long list of commits, I assume terminates at the merge base. My confusion is that this last commit is days ahead of where the branches diverged. (let's say that it's between `ch2` and `ch3` in my graph). And now I think, as a consequence, the `ch1` change appears in the diff of B, but in reverse (... + ahead of things that were removed, in fact, ch1 is actually the initial commit, so the diff looks like someone "applied" the initial commit to a subsequent change).  Could this explain our issues?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "terminates at the merge base": `git log` just keeps logging until it has printed every commit you've selected for printing. But if the merge base is ahead of where you think it should be, that means someone already did the merge you *wanted* to be doing here. I imagine you have a pretty tangled graph (this is common in real repositories, which are never as clean and neat as examples in books :-) ). Anyway, that's definitely *why* you get the merge result you don't-want-but-do-get. What to do *about* that is trickier.

Comment: Sorry, by terminating I meant that when I run `git log` on that hash, the first commit I see is where git believes the merge base is.  And the merge thing probably makes sense, because people will often commit to the release branch, and then merge to main (or vice versa...is this bad practice?). But what I don't understand is how git is going from that merge base to trying to apply the original commit over later commits. Is it based on the distance (time-wise) from the merge base?I want to understand, because it's happening often enough to make source control useless, as it guarantees nothing.

Comment: Merging back and forth between different branches isn't necessarily *bad*, but it creates complex graphs which are hard to reason about. So in that sense it's "bad". In any case, once Git has found the merge base, it *doesn't look at anything in between*: the merge process has three inputs, which are just the base and the two branch tips. The choice of *which* commit *is* the merge base is affected by the commit *graph*: the connections from each commit to its parent(s). So that's the only place "commit history" matters: that's what sets the merge base. After that, only the snapshots matter.

Comment: By the way, for (much) more about this, including all the graph theory that makes Git and Mercurial work, I have a not-very-far-along book I have been working on.  The early chapters on graph theory should be reasonably solid though. A rather raw pdf is available [here](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).

Comment: So we've potentially tracked it down to one commit that is treated as the merge base when it shouldn't be. What I fear happened is a commit was made with `git merge` instead of `commit`, creating a link in the git graph that shouldn't exist logically, but exists from the point of the history. That "merge" undid all the changes, because there was an attempt to undo it (from a gui, so the merge command potentially remained behind).  While a separate question technically, do you have any recommendations for undoing that link in the git graph?

Comment: You can't really *break* links, but you can impose substitutions using `git replace`. That might be a way to work with/around the problem. Note that replacement objects don't normally transfer from one repository to another, though. Replacements also require that you understand what you're doing at the graph level—they're very low level operations...